# How to use Particular Size Function out of more Size function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

[image]

I have included multiple jar files for designing UI in almost all jar files SIZE function is there. When I used to determine the siZe of File Its Not executing the SIZE function.

```
var sizeOfImage=$("#employeePic")[0].files[0].size;
```

When I click ctrl click on size ..it's showing many libraries which contains size function..thats why in run time it's not selectiong because of many SIZE Function

```
var form_data = new FormData();
var imageCount = document.getElementById("employeePic").files.length;
for (i = 0; i < imageCount; i++) {
    form_data.append("file", document.getElementById("employeePic").files[i]);
}
**var filesize=document.getElementById("employeePic").files[0].size();**
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "EmployeeManagerAdd", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("employeeJson", JSON.stringify(employeeJson));
xhr.send(form_data);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {alert('Successful....')
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you use `var sizeOfImage=$("#employeePic")[0].files[0].size;`?

Comment: In JS File...in Js file i am saving employee data along with Photo...In this am calling one fuction where am creating one json object of details and image as **FormData** ..here i want to validate the size of image

Comment: Is `.files[0].size;` used within `change` event? Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate?

Comment: i cant create jsfiddle right now..

Comment: _"In this am calling one fuction where am creating one json object of details and image as FormData ..here i want to validate the size of image"_ Can you include function text where `var sizeOfImage=$("#employeePic")[0].files[0].size;` is used at Question?

Comment: <input type='file' id='employeePic' size='40' name='employeePic' onchange='uploadfunction()'></input>

Comment: Are you expecting `size` to be `40`? See https://jsfiddle.net/p1gcxw5y/

Comment: i have mentioned jquery  method...u just check that...and see the screenshot i have mentioned

Comment: yes am expecting 40kb

Comment: See jsfiddle at previous comment. `files[0].size` returns size of selected `File` object, not attribute `size=40`

Comment: i got it...thanks a lot... instead of **.SIZE()** i want to use **.SIZE**

Answer (score 0):

[`.size()`](http://api.jquery.com/size/) returns `.length` of elements in jQuery collection, which is different from [`.size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/size) property of [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object. `.size()` is not a method of `File` or `FileList` objects.

To return expected result, remove `()` at

```
var filesize = document.getElementById("employeePic").files[0].size;
```

to reference `.size` property of `File` object

Comment: i want to get the file size... in multiplr libraries SiZe() function is available as i mentioned in screenshot... i want to use jQuery to get size of file ..but how can i include tat i size function has to use jquery at that time

Comment: _"i want to use jQuery to get size of file"_ jQuery is not necessary to return expected result. jQuery does not have a method which returns `size` property of `File` object. Have you read linked documentation of jQuery `.size()` method? Use `.files[0].size` to retrieve "The size, in bytes, of the data contained in the Blob object"

Comment: Thanks a lot.... Size is returning the file size.............From ! day i was Struggling to get file size.... now its come to end bcz of u..thanks